# Flutter Firebase Error (Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug')

Tags: firebase, android-studio, gradle, flutter, dart

I'm new to programming, and I'm very new to flutter and firebase. I'm experimenting with this code (https://github.com/tattwei46/flutter_login_demo), but I've run into an error. Everything should be the same except I changed the google-service.json and GoogleService.plist to match up with my firebase apps, and I edited home-page.dart. Here is what was printed out:

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Type com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf is referenced as an interface from `com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcfb`.","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
  >   Failed to transform artifact 'firebase-analytics-impl.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:11.4.2)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16}.
  >   Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: /Users/student/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/cfad2a10e4239993e5e793d023977752/jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-11.4.2/jars/classes.jar.
  >   Error while dexing.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 57s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Any solutions and/or ideas for what to look for? Flutter doctor reports no issues.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After looking at your logs and online search here some potential fixes

**1**
use classpath `com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3`

instead of

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1`
from github issue [1494](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1494#issuecomment-559214754)

**2** update your `pubspec.yaml`,
migrate the project to AndroidX,enable multidex

Comment: The first option worked for me. this is the saviour. thanks :)