# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception - Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'

Tags: java, android

This is what happened when I actually import a firestore dependency, all I thought it is about the connection but these errors happened all the time. Please help me

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform firebase-storage-19.2.1.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-incremental-transform=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=23, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Firebase Error (Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59584018/flutter-firebase-error-execution-failed-for-task-appmergeextdexdebug)

Comment: enable Multi dex

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add `maven.google.com` to your root level `build.gradle` file?

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

If you are using the android gradle plugin 3.x you can also use:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

- Also maybe you forgot to add **core** dependency

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```